# Press enter on the specific button using Pywinauto in Python

Tags: python, pywinauto, pyautogui

I am using pywinauto for entering the button in an application installed on windows 7.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys, KeySequenceError

app = Application().start()
send_keys("{ENTER}")
```

The above code opens the app and does the action ENTER. The problem is, it wrongly selected another button. Is there any way to specify the name of the button and hit the enter key using pywinautoin python.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's worth reading the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for core concept. In a few words you can do something like

```
app.window(title="Main Window Title").child_window(title="Button name", class_name="Button").click_input()
# or .click() which may not work in some specific cases
```

depending on

- what `[w.window_text() for w in app.windows()]` returns and
- what `app.window(title="Main Window Title").dump_tree()` prints.

Also it's important to distinguish `Application(backend="win32")` and `Application(backend="uia")`.